# Synchronisation between 2 renderPass

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

I have 2 renderpass: The main one is drawing the world. The second one draw a menu texture offscreen, in order to be used in the main renderPass as a texture. As the menu is not always displayed, the offscreen renderPass is optionnal.

I have some small rectangular glitch. It doesn't happend when the menu contains only few items.

I have added VkSubpassDependency in the offscreen renderPass.

I don't know if I need to change the VkSubpassDependency of the main renderPass.

I may need a vkCmdPipelineBarrier between the two renderpass? I've tried it without success.

Do I need VkMemoryBarrier?

The Main renderPass creation function comes directly from the oculus OVR SDK. I put it here so that you can see what's in subpassDescription:

```
bool ovrVkRenderPass_Create( ovrVkContext * context, ovrVkRenderPass * renderPass, const ovrSurfaceColorFormat colorFormat, const ovrSurfaceDepthFormat depthFormat, const ovrSampleCount sampleCount, const ovrVkRenderPassType type, const int flags, const ovrVector4f * clearColor, bool isMultiview )
{
renderPass->type = type;
renderPass->flags = flags;
renderPass->colorFormat = colorFormat;
renderPass->depthFormat = depthFormat;
renderPass->sampleCount = sampleCount;
renderPass->internalColorFormat = ovrGpuColorBuffer_InternalSurfaceColorFormat( colorFormat );
renderPass->internalDepthFormat = ovrGpuDepthBuffer_InternalSurfaceDepthFormat( depthFormat );
renderPass->internalFragmentDensityFormat = VK_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM;
renderPass->clearColor = *clearColor;

uint32_t attachmentCount = 0;
VkAttachmentDescription attachments[4];

// Optionally use a multi-sampled attachment.
if ( sampleCount > OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 )
{
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format = renderPass->internalColorFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples = (VkSampleCountFlagBits)sampleCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}
// Either render directly to, or resolve to the single-sample attachment.
if ( sampleCount <= OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 || EXPLICIT_RESOLVE == 0 )
{
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format = renderPass->internalColorFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}
// Optionally use a depth buffer.
if ( renderPass->internalDepthFormat != VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED )
{
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format = renderPass->internalDepthFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples = (VkSampleCountFlagBits)sampleCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}

uint32_t sampleMapAttachment = 0;
if( ( flags & OVR_RENDERPASS_FLAG_INCLUDE_FRAG_DENSITY ) != 0 )
{
    sampleMapAttachment = attachmentCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format = renderPass->internalFragmentDensityFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
    attachmentCount++;
}

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentReference;
colorAttachmentReference.attachment = 0;
colorAttachmentReference.layout     = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference resolveAttachmentReference;
resolveAttachmentReference.attachment   = 1;
resolveAttachmentReference.layout       = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentReference;
depthAttachmentReference.attachment = ( sampleCount > OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 && EXPLICIT_RESOLVE == 0 ) ? 2 : 1;
depthAttachmentReference.layout     = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference fragmentDensityAttachmentReference;
if ( ( flags & OVR_RENDERPASS_FLAG_INCLUDE_FRAG_DENSITY ) != 0 )
{
    fragmentDensityAttachmentReference.attachment = sampleMapAttachment;
    fragmentDensityAttachmentReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
}

VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription;
subpassDescription.flags = 0;
subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpassDescription.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
subpassDescription.pInputAttachments = NULL;
subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentReference;
subpassDescription.pResolveAttachments = &resolveAttachmentReference;
subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentReference;
subpassDescription.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
subpassDescription.pPreserveAttachments = NULL;

VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo;
renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = NULL;
renderPassCreateInfo.flags = 0;
renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = attachmentCount;
renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = attachments;
renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 0;
renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = NULL;

VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo multiviewCreateInfo;
const uint32_t viewMask = 0b00000011;
if ( isMultiview )
{
    multiviewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_MULTIVIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    multiviewCreateInfo.pNext = NULL;
    multiviewCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    multiviewCreateInfo.pViewMasks = &viewMask;
    multiviewCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 0;
    multiviewCreateInfo.correlationMaskCount = 1;
    multiviewCreateInfo.pCorrelationMasks = &viewMask;

    renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = &multiviewCreateInfo;
}

VkRenderPassFragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT fragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT;
if ( ( flags & OVR_RENDERPASS_FLAG_INCLUDE_FRAG_DENSITY ) != 0 )
{
    fragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    fragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT.fragmentDensityMapAttachment  = fragmentDensityAttachmentReference;

    fragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT.pNext = renderPassCreateInfo.pNext;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = &fragmentDensityMapCreateInfoEXT;
}

VK( vkCreateRenderPass( vk.device, &renderPassCreateInfo, VK_ALLOCATOR, &renderPass->renderPass ) );

return true;
}
```

Offscreen renderPass creation:

```
    // (...) create all images/ImageView for color and depth

    // (...) create the sampler

uint32_t attachmentCount = 0;
VkAttachmentDescription attachments[4];

// Optionally use a multi-sampled attachment.
if ( sampleCount > OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 )
{
    // Color attachment
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags          = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format         = colorFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples        = (VkSampleCountFlagBits)sampleCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp         = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp        = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp  = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout  = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}
// Either render directly to, or resolve to the single-sample attachment.
if ( sampleCount <= OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 || EXPLICIT_RESOLVE == 0 )
{
    // Color attachment
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags          = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format         = colorFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples        = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp         = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp        = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp  = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout  = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}
// Optionally use a depth buffer.
if ( depthFormat != VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED )
{
    // Depth attachment
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags              = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format             = depthFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples            = (VkSampleCountFlagBits)sampleCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp             = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR; // Clear attachments at the beginning of a render pass
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp            = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp      = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR; // Clear the contents within the render area to a uniform value (specified when render pass instance begun) 
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp     = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout      = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout        = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachmentCount++;
}
// Optionally use a fraqgment density map.
uint32_t sampleMapAttachment = 0;
if( ( flags & OVR_RENDERPASS_FLAG_INCLUDE_FRAG_DENSITY ) != 0 )
{
    sampleMapAttachment = attachmentCount;
    attachments[attachmentCount].flags          = 0;
    attachments[attachmentCount].format         = fragmentDensityFormat;
    attachments[attachmentCount].samples        = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].loadOp         = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].storeOp        = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilLoadOp  = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[attachmentCount].initialLayout  = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
    attachments[attachmentCount].finalLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
    attachmentCount++;
}

// Images used as color attachment
VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentReference;
colorAttachmentReference.attachment = 0;
colorAttachmentReference.layout     = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference resolveAttachmentReference;
resolveAttachmentReference.attachment   = 1;
resolveAttachmentReference.layout       = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentReference;
depthAttachmentReference.attachment = ( sampleCount > OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 && EXPLICIT_RESOLVE == 0 ) ? 2 : 1;
depthAttachmentReference.layout     = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference fragmentDensityAttachmentReference;
if ( ( flags & OVR_RENDERPASS_FLAG_INCLUDE_FRAG_DENSITY ) != 0 )
{
    fragmentDensityAttachmentReference.attachment = sampleMapAttachment;
    fragmentDensityAttachmentReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_DENSITY_MAP_OPTIMAL_EXT;
}

VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription;
subpassDescription.flags                    = 0;
subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint        = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpassDescription.inputAttachmentCount     = 0;
subpassDescription.pInputAttachments        = NULL;
subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount     = 1;
subpassDescription.pColorAttachments        = &colorAttachmentReference;
subpassDescription.pResolveAttachments      = ( sampleCount > OVR_SAMPLE_COUNT_1 && EXPLICIT_RESOLVE == 0 ) ? &resolveAttachmentReference : NULL;
subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment  = ( depthFormat != VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED ) ? &depthAttachmentReference : NULL;
subpassDescription.preserveAttachmentCount  = 0;
subpassDescription.pPreserveAttachments     = NULL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription;
    subpassDescription.flags = 0;
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDescription.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDescription.pInputAttachments = NULL;
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentReference;
    subpassDescription.pResolveAttachments = NULL;
    subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentReference;
    subpassDescription.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDescription.pPreserveAttachments = NULL;

    // Use subpass dependencies for layout transitions

    VkSubpassDependency dependencies[2];

    dependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependencies[0].dstSubpass = 0;
    dependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependencies[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependencies[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    dependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0;
    dependencies[1].dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    dependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    dependencies[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    // renderPass creation

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo;
    renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = NULL;
    renderPassCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = attachmentCount;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = attachments;
    renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
    // Use subpass dependencies
    renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = sizeof(dependencies);
    renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = dependencies;
    vkCreateRenderPass( vk.device, &renderPassCreateInfo, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenRenderPass );

    // (...) create vkCreateFramebuffer
```

Then, in the loop:

```
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmdBuffer, offscreenRenderPass, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE); // offscreen renderpass
// vkCmdDraws to draw the menu texture
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmdBuffer);

// Do I need a pipelineBarrier? This one doesn't solve anything
//vkCmdPipelineBarrier(vk.frame_cmd_buf, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// Do I need VkMemoryBarrier? (srcAccess/dstAccess?)

vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmdBuffer, mainRenderPass, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE); // main renderpass
// vkCmdDraw to draw the world
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmdBuffer);
```

Here is a screenshot of the bug, the pink background is the offscreen texture, apply on a curved canvas. I added pink background because without it, the screen is almost all black, so I can't even see the bugs. Notice the hole in the upper part of the character, the blue rectangles bug only changes with the movement of the character.

Thank for any help.

---

edit:

I should have tried before, I added the validation layer, and app crashed with error:

```
Dependency graph must be specified such that an earlier pass cannot depend on a later pass.
```

Based on my comprehension of the Vulkan specs chapter 7.1, pointed by  Sascha Willems, and after looking at his offscreen example on his github, I add these VkRenderPassCreateInfo to the main renderPass:

```
VkSubpassDependency dependencies[2];

dependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependencies[0].dstSubpass = 0;
dependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
dependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependencies[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
dependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
dependencies[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

dependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0;
dependencies[1].dstSubpass =  VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
dependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
dependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
dependencies[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
```

Now, the VkSubpassDependency for the two renderPass are very similar to the offscreen sample of Sasha, as I use his example to create my offscreen renderPass.

Without the validation error, bugs are still there.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's no need for an explicit barrier when using proper subpass depenencies. Can you post the missing parts of your code, esp. the ```VkAttachmentDescription```setup of your offscreen pass and also the subpass dependencies of the renderpass that's using the offscreen target (the one from OVR SDK). A screenshot or video of the actual problem may also help.

Comment: If the renderpass you get from the OVR SDK does not contain any explicit subpass dependencies, then the implicit ones as per chapter 7.1 of the Vulkan specs are used which may not be what you'd require for this scenario.

Comment: Thx Sascha. I put the full ovrVkRenderPass_Create() function, As you will see, there is no subpass dependencies, so I'm going to look at what you told me about chapter 7.1.

Comment: I tried adding a VkSubpassDependency to the main renderpass, visible in the "edit" at the end of my post, but I haven't had a change.

Answer (score 0):

These seem dubious:

> ```
> offscreenDependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
> offscreenDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
> ```

You described the problem as:

> The second one draw a menu texture offscreen, in order to be used in the main renderPass as a texture.

Yet your `dstAccessMask` doesn't include texture reading. You have several attachments there, but you're not using the image written in the first render pass as an attachment. So you should include the actual operations your renderpass is going to do to the image.

Also, `srcAccessMask = 0` basically says that the source isn't accessing anything. But the source clearly is; it's writing to an image as a color attachment. So you should tell Vulkan that.

Comment: Thx you Nicol, I have modified that part, you can see it in the last part of my question, but  still have the same bugs

Comment: There are several if statements that determine what the value ```storeOp```. Can you check if this is set to ```VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE```.

Comment: My bad, I changed condition for the real values. storeOp is not set to VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE. I don't know if it should?

Comment: For the attachment you want to read from yes, if it's not set then you have no guarantee at what remains in that attachment after the render pass has finished.

Comment: The attachment I want to read from, the offscreen color framebuffer, was already set to storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE. Did I misunderstand? I have a doubt as you ask for the setting of the main renderPass. I added the offscreen attachment description to my question. (There are still some conditions, but I think they are unrelated.)